# Grey screen in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, paintcomponent

so i using netbeans, and i'm starting to get into coding games... and i've done this so far with no errors, however when i run it just a grey box with my title "zachs game appears and thats it.... please help if you know the problem 1 -thank you

```
package swing9;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JavaApplication2 extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    int x, y, xDirection, yDirection;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 30);

    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {

                move();

                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public void move() {

        x += xDirection;
        y += yDirection;

        if (x <= 0)
            x = 0;

        if (x >= 300)
            x = 300;

        if (y <= 50)
            y = 50;

        if (y <= 300)
            y = 300;

    }

    public void seyXDir(int xdir) {

        xDirection = xdir;
    }

    public void setYDirection(int ydir) {

        yDirection = ydir;
    }

    public class AL extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {

                int setXDirection = -1;

            }

            if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
                int setXDirection = +1;

            }

            if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
                int setYDirection = -1;
            }

            if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
                int setYDirection = +1;

            }

        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == e.VK_LEFT) {
            int setXDirection = 0;
        }

        if (keyCode == e.VK_RIGHT) {
            int setXDirecetion = 0;
        }

        if (keyCode == e.VK_UP) {
           int setYDirectiom = 0;
        }

        if (keyCode == e.VK_DOWN) {
            int setYDirecction = 0;
        }

    }

    public JavaApplication2() {

        addKeyListener((KeyListener) new JavaApplication2.AL());

        setTitle("Zachs Game");
        setSize(300, 300);

        setResizable(false);

        setVisible(true);
        setBackground(Color.blue);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        x = 150;
        y = 150;

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("Play", 40, 40);
        g.setFont(font);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 15, 15);

        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new JavaApplication2();

        // threads

        Thread t1 = new Thread();
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Was `keyReleased()` supposed to be part of the `AL` class? I often find that the `@Override` marker is very handy for finding minor mistakes like that.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5)` is near enough to `Thread.sleep(0)` as makes no difference.  60fps is roughly `Thread.sleep(15)`, 25fps is roughly `Thread.sleep(40)`.  Most people won't see much difference over 30fps on most monitors...

Comment: Your `KeyListener` is not likely to ever fire as the `JFrame` itself can't receive focus as there are other components on top of it, consider using [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead

Answer (score 2):

`JFrame` or any of its super classes do not implement the `paintComponent` method so is never invoked. Check this yourself by adding the `@Override` annotation.

Move this method to a new class that extends `JComponent` and invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first statement.

Don't call `repaint` from within `paintComponent`, this create an infinite loop and degrades performance. [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) were designed to interact more easily with swing components. Use these over than raw Threads for periodic updates.

Aside: `JFrame` is not focusable by default so `KeyEvents` which require focus will not be triggered without making the window focusable. Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead.

Comment: (and don't call repaint inside any `paint` method and nothing is actually requesting a repaint when the model has changed...)